# Relation between Eigenvectors and $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there any relation between an eigenvector and $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$? Here I mean vector space of all linear maps:$V \rightarrow W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces and in my question these are $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R^3},\mathbb{R^3}$).

I understand that when we construct a diagonal matrix for example(which is change of basis) then there should be $n$ eigenvector to span the same space but I got a question which I don't understand: It says:

Suppose $S$ is the set of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $(1,2,3)$ an eigenvector is then is $S \subset \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$?

It does not say that this is the only eigenvector but it says $(1,2,3)$ is an eigenvector. I don't understand what does that mean? Can someone please tell me what is meant by that statement?

Comment: I edit the question :)

Comment: @anon What does eigenvector do ? I mean if i know that $S$ is set of all linear maps then it should be subset of $Hom(V,W)$ without that eigenvector, So why is there an eigenvector involved?

Comment: Doesn't the real question ask whether the set of linear maps which have a given  vector as an eigenvector, is a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(V, V)$?

Comment: @Bernard Aha. The only sensible interpretation.

Comment: @Bernard No , I checked again.

Comment: B.t.w., what are $V$ and $W$ with respect to $\mathbf R^3$?